# what is scope.$new(true) and how does it work

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to test a directive ( you can see full details at:
[Unit testing angular directive - very stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181725/unit-testing-angular-directive-very-stuck%20))

One of the things I am stuck on is finding out what `scope.$new(true)` means. From what I can find out it looks like $new creates a new child scope, but what is the (true) part and does angular do this automaticly because its not in my code yet it is still being thrown as the error `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'scope.$new(true)')`

Comment: `$scope.$new(true)` creates a new child scope that does not prototypically inherit from a parent scope - i.e. it is an isolate scope that does "see" properties defined in the parent scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), the boolean argument to `Scope.$new` specifies whether or not the new scope is an isolate scope. Isolate scopes do not inherit properties from their parent scope.

Isolate scopes are most often encountered when creating a directive and specifying `scope: {...}` in the options object. See [Isolating the Scope of a Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive) for more on that.